# scraping the html file saved in local system

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape an HTML file saved in my local file system (windows 10 os).

when I give the file path in the format

```
start_urls = ['file:///path/to/file/file_name.htm']
```

I get the error

> [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET file:///path/to/file/file_name.htm>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\path\to\file\file_name.htm'`

when I give the file path in the format

```
start_urls = ['path/to/file/file_name.htm']
```

I get the error

> [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests
> raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)

How can I read the local HTML file and **scrape** it in windows os?

Comment: Since you say you're on Windows, shouldn't your path include the drive letter? for example: 'file:///C:/Users/justin/Desktop/myfile.html'

Comment: you can always use Python to run local server `python3 -m http.server` https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html

Answer (score 3):

I think this is wrong to use `start_urls` in this case. Maybe you can try to read data in the file and then apply `Selector` to it?
Check this example:

```
>>> from scrapy import Selector
>>> f = open('example.html')
>>> sel = Selector(text=f.read())
>>> sel.css('head title::text').get()
Example title
```

If you need, you can put block with file reading inside function `start_requests`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the code in this way to **scrape** your own file saved in local system

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html5lib
myFile=open('C:/Users/CSE/AppData/Local/atom/app-1.42.0/practise.html','r')
soup=BeautifulSoup(myFile,"html5lib")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Inside open function first parameter is your file_path(though i have given here my own path) and the second parameter is the mode that you wants.

Comment: Note that when I tried to run this code it gave me error of:'unicodeescape' So we can avoid this error by changing the position of 'r' as here myFile=open(r'C:/Users/CSE/AppData/Local/atom/app-1.42.0/practise.html')